# Something instead goto?

Tags: c#

As I am beginner in C#, we only write in Console. The assignment requires we do not use "`goto`" which is what I am currently using.

You are asked a question at the end of console, If "yes", it returns me to the entrance, if "no" it goes to next question.

```
switch (pitanje)
{
    case ("da"):
        goto start;
    case ("ne"):
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        goto end;
    default:
        break;
}
```

So "start" is at the beginning(first entry), "end" stands in front of the last question in the console.

How do I accomplish this without `goto`

Comment: Consider studying (Google-ing) control flow tools such as `while` loops, `for` loops and such.  They may give you the answers you need.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy: It appears to be "How do I replicate the following without using a goto"

Comment: Don't use `GOTO` Yuk..it's a debugging nightmare use `break or continue`

Comment: The question concerns if there's an alternative to using goto

Comment: Dont use goto , http://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 2):

```
string pitanje = "";

while(pitanje != "ne")
{
    //start

    if(pitanje == "da")
        //logic

}
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
```

p.s. russian naming variables is not the best choice.

Also consider reading a classical article [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF) by Edsger W. Dijkstra. Also read his book on [Structured Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122005503). It makes a great point on how to structure your program in such way, that you can analyse and prove it's correctness.

Comment: "пытание" doesn't sound like Russian. Probably Serbian (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitanje)

Comment: It could mean "питание". Serbian is more plausible because of "ne", but we still have "не" as negation. Anyway, any language except English in source control is, well, questionable.

Comment: neither "пытание", or "питание" means "question" which seems to be the logical meaning of the variable name. As for acceptable language, at least the author is using latin alphabet. :)

Comment: Yeap, evidence points to your correctness. It didn't mean anything for me if variable name was question or nutrition (from Russian питание) and his name is probably not Russian. By the way, I saw Cyrillic comments in source code in one of my projects, that was at least disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this `switch` is the last part of your program, put a `while` loop that checks a variable around your program. Update that variable based on what the `switch` branch is taken.

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably forms a kind of loop. In that case you can replace it like this:

```
while (pitanje != "ne") {
    // Read content of pitanje …

    switch (pitanje) {
        case "da":
            continue;
        case "ne":
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            break;
    }
}
```

– No need for the `default` case. `continue` jumps back to the beginning of the loop. In the `ne` case you simply change the colour and then, in the loop header, your loop is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use break or continue. Or you can use a variable as a flag. also you  can use loops and conditions within. It completely depends on your program